# No Wireless Networks are available (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: wireless, macosx

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my MacBook Pro, using a thumb-drive and UNetbootin.
Right now, Ubuntu is the only operating system running on my computer. 
My problem is that I can't see any available networks that I can join and on my previous OS I could see all these networks but in Ubuntu I cannot see any networks showing up in the top right corner on the connection icon.

I am sure that all my settings are correct and I do have Enable Networking as true. I hope you can find the solution to this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Please check if your kernel module of your wifi adapter loaded (lsmod | grep ...)
2. Then check kernel message for any other error (dmesg)

Answer (score 0):

Few questions:

1) What model macbook Pro do you have?

You can flip it over its on top of the back plate

2) Can you get Ethernet if so plug it in and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

3) If step #2 does not work  can you paste the out put of

```
lspci | grep "Netowork"
```

Comment: I am sure that the MacBook Pro is late 2011 edition, when I start the mac up, it's running on the EFI boot if that is any help. When I run apt-get update, the terminal responds with 4 errors and the last line responds with 'Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.' The other commands seem to work fine.     The output for grep "Network" is    03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)

Comment: can you paste the 4 errors ?